# Setting Date() object to current time in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Rather than creating a new instance for each call, how do I simply update an already-existing Date() object to the current date/time?

Comment: `var aDate = /* some date */; aDate = Date()`

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is immutable. You have no choice but to create a new instance each time you want the current date/time.

```
var someDate = Date()
```

and later:

```
someDate = Date()
```

There's no other way to update `someDate` to the current date/time without creating a new `Date` instance.

There's nothing inefficient about this. Don't worry about premature optimizations.

Now if you want to use the current date in a loop or something such that multiple objects use the same date, then create the `Date` instance before the loop (or store in a class property) and reuse that value as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` objects are immutable, as rmaddy says in his answer. If you want the current date as a `Date` object, you need to create a new instance of Date using the `Date()` initializer. Just create a new Date any time you need the current date and don't worry about it.

If you want to avoid creating new Date objects (which is unlikely to be an issue) then you could use the `Date` static var `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`:

```
let currentInterval = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

That will give you a `TimeInterval` (which is a Double, a scalar value, rather than an object) representing the current number of seconds since the Cocoa reference date. You can then do math on that value, or even use it to later create a Date object, if desired.

Answer (score -1):

`Date()` returns the current date. You can use with your own logic.